# Not able to apply impulse to SKSpriteNode physics body

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am new to xcode's **sprite kit** and I'm an trying to apply an impulse to a `SKSpriteNode's` physics body.
Here is how I create the scene:

```
self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
        ballCategory = 1;
        wallCategory = 2;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = wallCategory;
```

Here is how I create the player AND give it its impulse:

```
player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:filePath];
    player.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
    player.position = CGPointMake(150, 250);
    player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:player.frame];
    player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ballCategory;
    player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = wallCategory;
    player.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
    player.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
    player.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0.0f;
    player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    [self addChild:player];
        CGVector impulse = CGVectorMake(100,100);
        [player.physicsBody applyImpulse:impulse];
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing because I've been following the **iOS Developer Library Sprite Kit** Programming Guide perfectly? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are creating the player's physicsBody as an edge body - these are always static (immovable by forces/impulses). You should change that line to:

```
player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.frame.size];
```

This example makes it a dynamic volume based on a rectangle which will be affected by physics forces. You can read up on the types of physics bodies [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html).